# What is a good singular way to check for types?

Tags: javascript

One simple approach used in libraries such as backbone is:

```
typeof o === type;
```

ES5 suggests using something similar to

```
(Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object ' + type + ']');
```

and Finally SO users have shared: ( [code review on getType](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23317/improving-istypeobj-and-gettypeobj) )

```
o.constructor === type;
```

Here are three fundamentally different ways

- using typeof
- using toString
- using the constructor property

I'd like to use these 3 methods to write a general checkType method.

Any advice on how best to combine these logically or why there are so may different ways to go about it.

Comment: `typeof` is the *only* keyword that you may use with undefined variables (that doesn't throw an error)

Comment: I put this in a function and just call it... `return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8,-1)`. I don't see why you would want to combine them? That will return Object, String, Array, etc..etc...

Comment: Maybe I check for arrays alot? lol. I wouldn't say it's useless. But I guess that is subjective.

Comment: A good combo is to use typeof by default for speed but if it returns Object, check again for Null and Array by using toString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that will help: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/

Comment: just what i was going to post!

Comment: It's a great description of the typeof operator and how to use it wisely!

Comment: I think a good thing that article points out is that (typeof({}) === typeof(null)) evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good comparison of the 3.

http://jsperf.com/constructor-vs-typeof-vs-tostring